# What is client-channel.google?

Tags: google, burp-suite, url

I am newbie in penetration testing. When I was using burp-suite, intercepting a dummy web-application when I found some strange URLs.

> 7.client-channel.google
>
> 10.client-channel.google...
> etc

I searched about it but found no information. I want to know what it is so that I can do better mapping of any web application.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for "what is client-channel.google"

And got this as one of the top 3 hits: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2589954?hl=en

> In order for users on your network to access Google Drive and Google
>   Docs editors, your firewall rules should connect to the following
>   hosts and ports. Otherwise, users may be blocked or denied access from
>   these services.
>
> ...
>
> [N].client-channel.google.com:443/HTTPS

My *assumption* is that you captured those URLs while using Chrome to connect to your dummy web application and caught traffic from Chrome to Google.

Comment: Google Hangouts seems to talk to those servers too.

Comment: @MikhailT. I'm sure many Google services might use it.